# How do I check if certain combinations of unordered values are in my appended list

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create an if statement that checks whether certain combinations of unordered values are in  my appended list.

```
if ("1" and "2" and "3") or ("1" and "4" and "7") in player1_inputs: 
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

No matter what set of numbers I put in the player1_inputs, I always get "Correct". Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: `("1" and "2" and "3") == "3"`, `("1" and "4" and "7") == "7"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Conditions are supposed to be explicit, i.e. you can't do `"1" and "2" in X` but you'll have to do `"1" in X and "2" in X`. What you're better off using is `set()`, and use `issubset()` instead of checking like you did

Comment: This should be the answer @Zionsof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [set logic](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for that:

```
player_inputs = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '7'}

subsets = [{'1', '2', '3'}, {'1', '4', '7'}, {'3', '4', '5'}]

for subset in subsets:
    if subset.issubset(player_inputs):
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Incorrect')
```

Comment: The last remark is incorrect. `issubset` can receive any iterable as argument, not just a set

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!